# Is there a way to figure out which .net symbols an assembly uses from a dependant assembly?

Tags: .net, assemblies, dependencies

Given an assembly A, that refers to Assembly B, how can I figure out methodically all the symbols (classes, constants, enums, etc) that A uses from B? Is there any tool that can tell me that?

PS: I need it to analyse how "entrenched" is the dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for visual studio. [This](http://www.thushanfernando.com/index.php/2009/06/01/net-tools-ndepend-static-analysis-tool-leave-t-pain-behind/) articles discusses it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

One low-tech way to discover dependencies:  In Visual Studio, open assembly A's project.  Remove assembly B from A's list of assembly references.  You can do a build, or just wait for the auto errors to start filling up the error list window.

Presto, a pretty comprehensive list of what and how much A needs from B.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ReSharper, open assembly A in VS and expand the project's References folder. Right click on the reference to B, and select "Find Dependent Code". ReSharper will navigate though your project and find all uses of types contained in B.